# Update nodejs app on Google cloud app engine from github

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-platform

I have a nodejs app on Google cloud app engine which I cloned from my GitHub repo, after some time i added some files to my GitHub repo. How I update my node app on Google cloud? Do I have to delete it and clone again or can just add the updated files?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a build trigger.

> A build trigger instructs Container Builder to automatically build
>   your image whenever there are changes pushed to the build source. You
>   can set a build trigger to re-build your images on any changes to the
>   source repository, or only changes that match certain criteria.

Currently build triggers support

- Google Cloud Source Repository
- GitHub
- Bitbucket

More details about build triggers can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/running-builds/automate-builds).